# was sure or could be sure?

Tags: modal-verbs

Are the following sentences natural?

> John said he would help Mary, but I could not be sure when he would come back.
>
> John said he would help Mary, but I was not sure when he would come back.

What difference, if any, is there between "was not sure" and "could not be sure"?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: What's the time frame?  Each is a slightly different perspective on when the statement and the return happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version with **could** expresses past capability (can -> could), here negated.  It was not possible for you to be sure. There is an implied *hindrance* or *impediment* to you being certain.

The version with **was** expresses a simpler past fact: you were not sure.